# React I want to add text to the react-chart-2 tooltip

Tags: reactjs, react-chartjs-2

I am using react-chart-2.
Hover over the graph to see the tooltip. I want to display a % to the right of the number, like 30%.
How can I add the % character to the tooltip? Also, how can I set the left value to a minimum of 0 and a maximum of 100?

[code](https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-frost-19qv9?file=/src/App.tsx:0-917)

```
import "./styles.css";
import { Line } from "react-chartjs-2";

const App = () => {
  const data = {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "test",
        data: [30, 10, 10, 40, 70, 10, 30],
        fill: false,
        backgroundColor: "#F7C520",
        borderColor: "#F7C520",
        hoverBackgroundColor: "#E6B71E",
        hoverBorderColor: "#E6B71E"
      }
    ]
  };

  const options = {
    responsive: true,
    tooltips: {
      mode: "label"
    },
    elements: {
      line: {
        fill: false
      }
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [
        {
          display: true,
          gridLines: {
            display: true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>Mixed data Example</h2>
      <Line data={data} options={options} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: I suggest starting by confirming the version of react-chartjs-2 you're using, as in your last question. Your code is compatible with react-chartjs-2 v2, but the version of it you're using in the sandbox is v3.

Comment: I have checked but cannot implement it properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ChartJS provides a callback that allows you to [customize the contents of your tooltip](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#label-callback). ChartJS also has many [other Tooltip callbacks](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#tooltip-callbacks) that come in handy for customizing the look and feel of your graphs, and react-chartjs-2, being a wrapper around ChartJS, allows the same functionality.

Add a `plugins` object containing tooltip configuration as below:

```
    plugins: {
      tooltip: {
        callbacks: {
          label: (context: any) => {
            let label = "";
            if (context.parsed.y) {
              label = context.parsed.y + "%"
            }
            return label;
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Resulting in:

[image: tooltip with a percentage sign added]

As for your other question, you seem to have figured it out in your sandbox already. Set the *min* and *max* values on your axis to the desired values.